# Check if Windows is activeted via wmi filter

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo, get-wmiobject

I want to get a message if Windows not activated

I create gpo that run message on logon

If i run this filter via wmi filter
`Get-wmiobject -query 'select licensestatus from softwarelicensingproduct where LicenseStatus like 1'`

I get the message.

But if run this filter
`Get-wmiobject -query 'select licensestatus from softwarelicensingproduct where LicenseStatus like 0'`

I get message on all the computers - activate and not activate

Is it possible to check all computers where the  **where LicenseStatus like 1** does not work?

I try to write this with **not like**

`Get-wmiobject -query 'select licensestatus from softwarelicensingproduct where not LicenseStatus like 1'`

It is not work. its work  like **LicenseStatus like 0**

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-check-the-license-status-of-windows-8/) can help, or try `Invoke-Command { (cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr) -join '' } -ComputerName xy`

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you're looking for all objects where `SoftwareLicensingProduct` is **NOT 1** then the syntax should be:

```
Get-WMIObject -Query 'SELECT LicenseStatus FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE LicenseStatus != 1'
```

Comment: i try this syntax on powershell and i get all the 0. like not 0.
in all computer have 0 and if it active have 1. i need to check whare not have just 1.

Comment: @yosi not sure I understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: when i write "WHERE LicenseStatus != 1" i get all the  who's  not equal to 1. iI know there is more, I want to check if 1 does not exist. It is possible?

Comment: To check if there is any object with value of 1 just use `LicenseStatus = 1` instead, if you get a result then you know it exist if you don't get anything then there isn't any object with that value.

Comment: I want to know if windows activated, if no run script. But in the wmi filter i can run script  if i  have somting. Then i need to know if LicenseStatus  not equal to 1 and any other number

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a GPO WMI filter for clients with activation `SELECT LicenseStatus FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE Name LIKE "%Windows%" AND PartialProductKey IS NOT NULL AND LicenseStatus =1`
For windows clients without activation `SELECT LicenseStatus FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE Name LIKE "%Windows%" AND PartialProductKey IS NOT NULL AND LicenseStatus !=1`